# When to use Good luck vs. Congratulations?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

When to use **good luck** and **congratulations**?

For example, suppose someone says "*I'm doing an exam*", so we respond by saying "*Good luck!*"

[Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/congratulation#congratulation__4) say '*Congratulations* is used when you want to congratulate somebody' so is it possible to use *congratulations* to wish instead of *good luck* in my example?

Comment: _"Good luck"_ comes before their success - you are saying you hope they will succeed.  _"Congratulations"_ comes after the success is achieved, and you are saying that you observed their success and approve of it.

Comment: Also - this hypothetical someone should say either _"I am taking an exam"_ or _"I am taking exams."_

Comment: Adding to what @Adam already said - you cannot congratulate someone for something they have yet to achieve, you can only wish them luck that they will achieve it. [btw, Br Eng would allow for 'do', even though 'take' is better]

Comment: The dictionary definition describes congratulate as "saying that you are happy about their good luck or success". If someone says "I am doing an exam" you would only congratulate them if the fact that they are taking an exam represents some type of success or good luck. For example, if only a few people were allowed to take that exam because of some other criteria.

Comment: @Adam please write up your comment as an answer, so this StackExchange question will include a definitive answer.  You may include information from other comments.

Comment: Need to get back to my real job.  If someone wants to use my comment as partial basis of a thorough, carefully written answer, I will take no offense, and will come back and +1 it later.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis The question is only an hour old. I think we can wait a bit to see if someone with more time on their hands can combine the commentary into a definitive answer. In my opinion, the linked definition in the question answers the question and more clarification from the asker as to why the definition wasn't very clear would help make a better answer. They need to be given some time to read the comments though.

Comment: @ColleenV You're absolutely right.  In fact, it appears that someone below actually did put together a more comprehensive answer.  I should have waited.... ;)

Answer (score 5):

### ***Definition***

The definition you referred to is [Oxford Learners Dictionaries: **congratulation**:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/congratulation) "1 congratulations [plural] a message congratulating somebody (= saying that you are happy about their good luck or success)."

- **"Congratulations"** comes after the success is achieved, and you are saying that you ***observed their success or good luck*** and approve of it.
- **"Good luck"** must come before their success - you are saying you hope they will succeed.

### ***Congratulations and good luck!***

You could congratulate someone for taking a prestigious exam, such as a [bar exam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_examination), especially if the person was expressing a positive sentiment at the fact that they had finally reached this point:

- Jane: "Hey Joe, guess what!"

  Joe: "What!"

  Jane: "I'm almost finished!  Tomorrow I'm sitting for the bar exam!"

  Joe: "Congratulations!"

  (You might also say "Congratulations! And good luck!")

### ***"Taking an exam" vs. "doing an exam"***

While "I'm taking an exam" is much more common, there are other phrases that are acceptable or even preferred within certain dialects of English.  Note the following Google N-Gram:

[image: Google N-Gram]
[Google N-Gram: *do an exam,doing an exam,take an exam,taking an exam,sit an exam,sitting an exam,sit for an exam,sitting for an exam,have an exam,having an exam,got an exam*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+an+exam%2Cdoing+an+exam%2Ctake+an+exam%2Ctaking+an+exam%2Csit+an+exam%2Csitting+an+exam%2Csit+for+an+exam%2Csitting+for+an+exam%2Chave+an+exam%2Chaving+an+exam%2Cgot+an+exam&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20an%20exam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoing%20an%20exam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20an%20exam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctaking%20an%20exam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csit%20an%20exam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csitting%20an%20exam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csit%20for%20an%20exam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csitting%20for%20an%20exam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20an%20exam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chaving%20an%20exam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20an%20exam%3B%2Cc0)

Some of these results have a different context, such as a doctor who says, "I'm doing an exam" is performing an exam on someone.  However, there are instances of "doing an exam" referring to the same meaning as "taking an exam" within the exact same idiomatic scenario.  (There are also some subtle cases in different scenarios that could influence usage.) It would be conservative to use the phrase "I'm taking an exam" unless the culture you're in uses a different idiomatic phrase.

---

<sup>Credit to @Adam and other commenters for ideas and content of this answer.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take the driving test tomorrow. Good Luck!

I have got a nice job in a bank. Good luck!

The phrase "good luck" is used when you wish somebody success in something he is going to do.

I have passed the driving test. Congratulations!

I have been promoted to Sales Manager. Congratulations!

I won the jackpot. Congratulations!

You say "congratulations" to somebody to tell him that you are pleased that he has achieved something  or succeeded in.